# Sorting objects in an arraylist by price attributes

Tags: java, arraylist

Im working on this really small project, I've got an arraylist of car objects and im trying to print all the cars out in price ascending order. When i look around online every seems to be doing it with an array rather than are arraylist?

Any ideas on how i can make this possible with an array list? Below is the code i have.

```
public ArrayList<Car> sortPriceAcending(ArrayList<Car> cars) {

    ArrayList<Car> sortedCars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    Car temp;

    for (int j = 0; j < cars.size() - 1; j++) {

        for (int i = 0; i < cars.size() - 1; i++) {
            Car car = (Car) cars.get(i);
            Car car1 = (Car) cars.get(i + 1);
            if (car.getPrice() > car1.getPrice()) {
                temp = car;
                cars.get(i) = cars.get(i + 1);
                cars.get(i + 1) = temp;
                sortedCars = cars;

            }
        }
    }
    return sortedCars;
}
```

Comment: ou can use java.util.Compartor<T> interface if you want to sort on the basis of more than one attribute of the object.

- You will have to use Collections.sort(List<?> l, Comparator c), Example:  class yourComparatorimplements Comparator<Car> {

        public int compare(OBJ obj1, OBJ obj2) {

            return obj1.getAttribute().compareTo(obj2.getAttribute());
        }
    }

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many sorting algorithms available. Java itself already offers a good one and you can just use it with `Collections#sort` ([official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)). The method accepts any kind of `List` and `ArrayList` is one of them.

Therefore you need to define on which order you want to sort, you want to sort by prices.

---

You can define a **natural ordering** on your cars by implementing `Comparable` like this:

```
public class Car implements Comparable<Car> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Car other) {
        return Integer.compare(this.getPrice(), other.getPrice());
    }

    // The other stuff of the car class
}
```

After that you can just use `Collections.sort(cars)` and it will sort based on this natural ordering you have defined.

---

However for general cars it might not be the best idea that their natural ordering is on prices. Therefore you can always define a `Comparator` object and use this for the ordering:

```
public class CarPriceComparator extends Comparator<Car> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Car first, Car second) {
        return Integer.compare(first.getPrice(), second.getPrice());
    }
}
```

And you can use it with `Collections.sort(cars, new CarPriceComparator())`.

---

If you like **Lambda expressions** and **method references** which came with **Java 8** you can also define the equivalent `Comparator` with less code like seen here:

```
Collections.sort(cars, Comparator.comparingInt(Car::getPrice))
```

Comment: whoa, java 8 has made it simple

Answer (score 0):

Hey Have you tried using comparator interface?
If you just have to sort always with price only try using comparable interface.
You can refer the following link for details :

Let me know if you need more details

https://www.javatpoint.com/difference-between-comparable-and-comparator